# Input table inside tikzpicture de-centers table? Beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, beamer, threeparttable

I am inputting a table inside a `\begin{tikzpicture}` to be able to use the coordinator calculator so I don't have to specify it everytime. I am having a headache since it is un-centering the table. Without the tikzpicture engulfing the `\input` command, the table fits the beamer and is centered. With it, the table shifts to the right and doesn't fit the slide.

Full sample code that replicates the problem exactly:

```
  \documentclass[10pt, aspectratio=169]{beamer}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{threeparttable}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes}
    \usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame}
    
        \begin{table}[H]
            \begin{center}
                \scalebox{0.5}{
                    \begin{threeparttable}
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                    \node (table) {\begin{tabular}{l*{7}{c}}
    \toprule
                                    &\multicolumn{3}{c}{BLABLA}&\multicolumn{4}{c}{BLABLA}\\\cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-8}
                                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(6)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(7)}\\
                                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{BLABLA}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{BLABLA}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{BLABLA}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{BLABLA}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{BLABLA}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{BLABLA}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{BLABLA}\\
    \midrule
    BLABLABLABLABLABLALBALBAL          &     0.01&     0.09&     0.07&     0.10&     0.14&     0.14&     0.14\\
                                    &   (0.03)&   (0.04)&   (0.03)&   (0.04)&   (0.05)&   (0.04)&   (0.05)\\
                                    &   [0.65]&   [0.01]&   [0.02]&   [0.01]&   [0.00]&   [0.00]&   [0.00]\\
    \addlinespace
    BLABLABLABLABLABLALBALBAL      &     0.01&     0.07&     0.07&     0.04&     0.05&    -0.01&    -0.03\\
                                    &   (0.02)&   (0.03)&   (0.03)&   (0.05)&   (0.05)&   (0.06)&   (0.04)\\
                                    &   [0.54]&   [0.02]&   [0.02]&   [0.36]&   [0.38]&   [0.91]&   [0.49]\\
    \addlinespace
    BLABLABLABLABLABLALBALBAL             &    -0.01&    -0.06&    -0.01&     0.04&    -0.03&    -0.02&     0.01\\
                                    &   (0.02)&   (0.03)&   (0.03)&   (0.03)&   (0.03)&   (0.04)&   (0.03)\\
                                    &   [0.60]&   [0.05]&   [0.78]&   [0.19]&   [0.32]&   [0.67]&   [0.85]\\
    \addlinespace
    BLABLABLABLABLABLALBALBAL  $\times$ &     0.03&    -0.05&    -0.02&     0.01&    -0.03&     0.01&    -0.03\\
    BLABLABLABLABLABLALBALBAL          &   (0.03)&   (0.04)&   (0.04)&   (0.05)&   (0.06)&   (0.06)&   (0.06)\\
                                    &   [0.27]&   [0.23]&   [0.69]&   [0.79]&   [0.64]&   [0.85]&   [0.65]\\
    \addlinespace
    BLABLABLABLABLABLALBALBAL $\times$ &     0.03&     0.10&     0.02&    -0.03&    -0.06&    -0.04&    -0.07\\
    BLABLABLABLABLABLALBALBAL              &   (0.03)&   (0.04)&   (0.04)&   (0.05)&   (0.05)&   (0.05)&   (0.05)\\
                                    &   [0.30]&   [0.01]&   [0.61]&   [0.59]&   [0.30]&   [0.43]&   [0.15]\\
    \midrule
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}};
                    \draw [red,ultra thick,rounded corners]
                      ($(table.south west) !.61! (table.north west)$)
                      rectangle 
                      ($(table.south east) !.77! (table.north east)$);
                    \end{tikzpicture}   
                    \end{threeparttable}
                }
            \end{center}
        \end{table}
        
        
    \end{frame}
    
    \begin{frame}
    
        \begin{table}[H]
            \begin{center}
                \scalebox{0.5}{
                    \begin{threeparttable}
                        \begin{tabular}{l*{7}{c}}
    \toprule
                                    &\multicolumn{3}{c}{BLABLA}&\multicolumn{4}{c}{BLABLA}\\\cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-8}
                                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(6)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(7)}\\
                                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{BLABLA}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{BLABLA BLABLA}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{BLABLA}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{BLABLA}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{BLABLA}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{BLABLA}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{BLABLA}\\
    \midrule
    BLABLABLABLABLABLALBALBAL          &     0.01&     0.09&     0.07&     0.10&     0.14&     0.14&     0.14\\
                                    &   (0.03)&   (0.04)&   (0.03)&   (0.04)&   (0.05)&   (0.04)&   (0.05)\\
                                    &   [0.65]&   [0.01]&   [0.02]&   [0.01]&   [0.00]&   [0.00]&   [0.00]\\
    \addlinespace
    BLABLABLABLABLABLALBALBAL      &     0.01&     0.07&     0.07&     0.04&     0.05&    -0.01&    -0.03\\
                                    &   (0.02)&   (0.03)&   (0.03)&   (0.05)&   (0.05)&   (0.06)&   (0.04)\\
                                    &   [0.54]&   [0.02]&   [0.02]&   [0.36]&   [0.38]&   [0.91]&   [0.49]\\
    \addlinespace
    BLABLABLABLABLABLALBALBAL             &    -0.01&    -0.06&    -0.01&     0.04&    -0.03&    -0.02&     0.01\\
                                    &   (0.02)&   (0.03)&   (0.03)&   (0.03)&   (0.03)&   (0.04)&   (0.03)\\
                                    &   [0.60]&   [0.05]&   [0.78]&   [0.19]&   [0.32]&   [0.67]&   [0.85]\\
    \addlinespace
    BLABLABLABLABLABLALBALBAL  $\times$ &     0.03&    -0.05&    -0.02&     0.01&    -0.03&     0.01&    -0.03\\
    BLABLABLABLABLABLALBALBAL          &   (0.03)&   (0.04)&   (0.04)&   (0.05)&   (0.06)&   (0.06)&   (0.06)\\
                                    &   [0.27]&   [0.23]&   [0.69]&   [0.79]&   [0.64]&   [0.85]&   [0.65]\\
    \addlinespace
    BLABLABLABLABLABLALBALBAL $\times$ &     0.03&     0.10&     0.02&    -0.03&    -0.06&    -0.04&    -0.07\\
    BLABLABLABLABLABLALBALBAL              &   (0.03)&   (0.04)&   (0.04)&   (0.05)&   (0.05)&   (0.05)&   (0.05)\\
                                    &   [0.30]&   [0.01]&   [0.61]&   [0.59]&   [0.30]&   [0.43]&   [0.15]\\
    \midrule
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
                    \end{threeparttable}
                }
            \end{center}
        \end{table}
        
        
    \end{frame}
    
    
    
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Don't encase the `tikzpicture` environment in a `threeparttable` environment.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why are you using `threeparttable` here? The three expected (though not required) parts of a `threeparttable` environment are the `\caption` directive, a `tabular`-like environment, and a `tablenotes` environment. Your `table` environments lack 2 of the 3 expected parts. There's absolutely nothing useful to be achieved by employing the `threeparttable` machinery in this way.

Comment: Hi @Mico, I use threeparttables in almost all tables because they normally have the three things you mentioned. This is a table for a slide, and I normally just copy the structure and change what is in the \input. I also removed captions here just for show.

So, removing the threeparttable should work?

Comment: Please see the answer I just posted for some additional thoughts about your table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- As discussed in the comments, removing the `threeparttable` wrapper -- which does absolutely nothing useful here anyway, as there are no `\caption` or `\tnote` directives and there is no `tablenotes` environment -- takes care of the immediate issue.
- As the `beamer` document class is in use, you might as well remove the `\begin{table}` and `\end{table}` statements too. In `beamer` documents, `table` and `figure` environments don't do anything useful since they don't "float" (in the LaTeX-specific sense of the word).
- I'd also replace `\scalebox{0.5}{...}` with `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{...}` and get rid of the `\begin{center}` and `\end{center}` statements.
- The folks in the audience of your `beamer`-based talk may appreciate it if you use the `\frametitle` directive to provide the equivalent of a table caption.
- Separately, *regardless* of which document class you may employ, do please get rid of the multitude of `\multicolumn{1}{c}{...}` wrappers. E.g., do please replace

  ```
  &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(6)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(7)}\\
  ```

  with the far more reader-friendly and easier-to-decipher-and-debug

  ```
  & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) & (6) & (7) \\
  ```

---

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt, aspectratio=169]{beamer}
%% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,plotmarks,calc}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Provide a table caption here}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%  % better to use `\resizebox` than `\scalebox` here
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (table) {%
    \begin{tabular}{@{} l *{7}{c} @{}}
    \toprule
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{BLABLA} & \multicolumn{4}{c@{}}{BLABLA} \\
        \cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(l){5-8}
        & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) & (6) & (7) \\
        & BLABLA & BLABLA & BLABLA & BLABLA & BLABLA & BLABLA & BLABLA \\
    \midrule
    BLABLABLABLABLABLALBALBAL      &     0.01&     0.09&     0.07&     0.10&     0.14&     0.14&     0.14\\
        &   (0.03)&   (0.04)&   (0.03)&   (0.04)&   (0.05)&   (0.04)&   (0.05)\\
        &   [0.65]&   [0.01]&   [0.02]&   [0.01]&   [0.00]&   [0.00]&   [0.00]\\
    \addlinespace
    BLABLABLABLABLABLALBALBAL      &     0.01&     0.07&     0.07&     0.04&     0.05&    -0.01&    -0.03\\
        &   (0.02)&   (0.03)&   (0.03)&   (0.05)&   (0.05)&   (0.06)&   (0.04)\\
        &   [0.54]&   [0.02]&   [0.02]&   [0.36]&   [0.38]&   [0.91]&   [0.49]\\
    \addlinespace
    BLABLABLABLABLABLALBALBAL      &    -0.01&    -0.06&    -0.01&     0.04&    -0.03&    -0.02&     0.01\\
        &   (0.02)&   (0.03)&   (0.03)&   (0.03)&   (0.03)&   (0.04)&   (0.03)\\
        &   [0.60]&   [0.05]&   [0.78]&   [0.19]&   [0.32]&   [0.67]&   [0.85]\\
    \addlinespace
    BLABLABLABLABLABLALBALBAL $\times$ &     0.03&    -0.05&    -0.02&     0.01&    -0.03&     0.01&    -0.03\\
    BLABLABLABLABLABLALBALBAL          &   (0.03)&   (0.04)&   (0.04)&   (0.05)&   (0.06)&   (0.06)&   (0.06)\\
        &   [0.27]&   [0.23]&   [0.69]&   [0.79]&   [0.64]&   [0.85]&   [0.65]\\
    \addlinespace
    BLABLABLABLABLABLALBALBAL $\times$ &     0.03&     0.10&     0.02&    -0.03&    -0.06&    -0.04&    -0.07\\
    BLABLABLABLABLABLALBALBAL          &   (0.03)&   (0.04)&   (0.04)&   (0.05)&   (0.05)&   (0.05)&   (0.05)\\
        &   [0.30]&   [0.01]&   [0.61]&   [0.59]&   [0.30]&   [0.43]&   [0.15]\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}};

    \draw [red,ultra thick,rounded corners]
          ($(table.south west) !.61! (table.north west)$)
          rectangle 
          ($(table.south east) !.77! (table.north east)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}%   <-- don't forget this comment symbol
} % end of scope of \resizebox directive
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Mico. This is really helpful. The multiple multicolumns are artifacts of the statistical softwares that produce the tables in TeX format.